# AttributeError: 'SlideShapes' object has no attribute 'text_frame'

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am using `python-pptx` library for editing powerpoint presentation in python. But on running the below script:

```py
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation('path/to/presentation.pptx')
slide = prs.slides[0]
shape = slide.shapes
shape.text_frame.text = "Introduction"
```

the error that arises is:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 3
      1 slide = prs.slides[0]
      2 shape = slide.shapes
----> 3 shape.text_frame.text = "Introduction"

AttributeError: 'SlideShapes' object has no attribute 'text_frame'
```

Here I am using `python-pptx==0.6.21`. Is there any method for the same?

Comment: From the [Documentation](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#pptx.shapes.shapetree.SlideShapes:~:text=MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.TEXT_BOX.-,text,text%20of%20the%20shape%20and%20provides%20access%20to%20text%20formatting%20properties.,-AdjustmentCollection%20objects) I would think that you can either use `text_frame` or `text` but not both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have removed `text` and the code ran successfully. But how am I suppose to add text into it? I tried the following: `textframe = shape.text_frame` and `textframe.text = "Introduction"`. But this results in another `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'`. How to add text to the text frame?

Comment: I have never worked with that, and it sounds like you also didn't. Maybe read the documentation or look up a guide.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Will look into the docs itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't that be

```
shape = slide.shapes[0]
```

as it's the first shape you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't considered that there exists multiple shapes.